# Adding double quote in datarow after converting into csv files

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I manage to convert all my data from SharePoint into CSV and save it into local environment. I miss look over it and saw there is a comma in my data and it created a new row into my csv.

This is output of my CSV result.

```
0|1|2|3|4
0|1|2,3|4|5
```

I already try to remove the comma and I'm being told that this is not a good way to do it. After looking into several question inside StackOverFlow I'm still stuck on it.

```
    private static void ExportToCSV(DataTable dTblSPGroupUser, StreamWriter sw, clsReport rule, string sFileName, string strDelimiter)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dTblSPGroupUser.Rows) // Now write all the rows.
            {
                var builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                foreach (clsField metadataItems in rule.Indexing)
                {
                    if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[metadataItems.FieldName.ToString()]))
                    {
                        builder.Append(dr[metadataItems.FieldName.ToString()].ToString());
                    }
                    builder.Append(strDelimiter);
                }
                string sData = builder.ToString();
                sData = sData.Remove(sData.Length - 1);

                // This is part I try to check
                if (sData.Contains(", "))
                {
                    sData = string.Format("\"{0}\"", sData);

                // What I should add here?
                } 

                    sw.Write(sData);
                    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
                    //sData = ""; No need to clear after write newLine.
                }
                sw.Close();
                Log("File " + sFileName + " Closed");
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I try to use trim and few other method it seem to be fail. Any way I could add double column into it since I'm reading it by row. Yes, I do believe there is hundred of solution it this web, but I can't find 1 that can fix my problem. Please do advice.

My expected output :-

```
0|1|2|3|4
0|1|"2,3"|4|5
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is that the only comma in the "CSV"?

Comment: So far we only got like 400 row. Within that row there is only 4 row that have comma. The rest is ok. Any how I can add " " between it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an extra space here: 
sData.Contains(", ")

Should be:

sData.Contains(",")

Comment: Yup, cause inside the data it contain (", ") in that particular row. I try to trim that comma but seem not a good way since I'm editing the data inside. Anyway I could put " " between that data?

Comment: You can enclose column value in quotes, CSV allows that and will strip external quotes when parsing. I don't know what you mean by "between that data". Between what data exactly?

Comment: I don't understand what your input is and what your desired output is, please show both.

Comment: Sorry my output is 0|1|2,3|4|5. My desire is 0,1|"2,3"|4|5 I just wanna have comma between data which contain comma.

Comment: Or every row lets have "0"|"1"|"2,3"|"4"|"5" each row how double quotes would be ok for me. Please do advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
            var builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder("\"");
            foreach (clsField metadataItems in rule.Indexing)
            {
                if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[metadataItems.FieldName.ToString()]))
                {
                    builder.Append(dr[metadataItems.FieldName.ToString()].ToString());
                }
                builder.Append("\""+ strDelimiter +"\"");
            }

            string sData = builder.ToString();
            //sData = sData.Remove(sData.Length - 1);
            sData = sData.Remove(sData.Length - 1,1);

                sw.Write(sData);
                sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
            }
            sw.Close();
            Log("File " + sFileName + " Closed");
```

This would make all your data would have " "|" ". Thanks.